# PWA is adding out-of-scope sites to history stack

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm working with a PWA that has oAuth logins. I've specified my PWA's scope as:

```
scope: "https://app.myapp.com"
```

So that any navigation to an out-of-scope URL would trigger an in-app browser.

In my code, when doing oAuth, I send users to the authorisation url with:

```
window.location.href = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client…"
```

This opens the in-app browser for oAuth which allows me to login, once done the user is sent back to my app.

HOWEVER, when I then call `history.go(-1)` the user is sent to `"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client…"` again instead of the page they were previously on.

It looks like even though the authorisation URL is not in-scope and opened in an in-app browser, it's still added to the history.

Is this a bug? I can't find any information about how history stack and in-app browser is handled.

Video of the behavior can be found [here](https://imgur.com/Vionv1P).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. You're using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) which keeps track of your session history. When you navigate the user to your oAuth URL, it is added to the history state [for that session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API#:%7E:text=As%20the%20user%20visits%20new%20pages%2C%20for%20example%20by%20clicking%20links%2C%20those%20new%20pages%20are%20added%20to%20the%20session%20history). Once the user is redirect back to your app, the last entry will be oAuth URL (-1).

You could easily get around this by going back two entries (-2) or editing/removing the last entry with [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) and [history.deleteUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteUrl).

Comment: I had no idea `history.deleteUrl` even existed, thank you!